# elements at the bottom of divs

Tags: html, css

I was wondering in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/D4xdE/) example how to have the last paragraph element to be at the bottom of the box if it's possible (you made need to re-size the window area)

css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /* top row */
    .col .well{ 
        margin-bottom: -99999px;
        padding-bottom: 99999px;   
    }
    .col-well {
        display:inline-block; height:100%   
    }
    .col-well p {
        vertical-align:bottom 
    }
    /* bottom row */
    .col-base{ 
        margin-top: -15px; /* cut off top portion of bottom wells */
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .row.base{
        display:none;
    }
}

.col-wrap{
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: You mean the whole grey box or only the last 'right column' word?

Comment: the last paragrahp in the box on the left so it stays fixed at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

```
.well{ 
    position: relative;
    min-height: 210px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.well > p:last-child {

    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;

}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0vaorvx/1/)